# Как правильно вывести таблицу из MySQL на JSP?

Tags: jdbc, java, mysql

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как ПРАВИЛЬНО сделать вывод таблицы из БД на JSP-страницу на основе `JDBC` (без внесения логики на `JSP`)?

Answer (score 5):

Правильно это:

1. Получить данные в сервлете/контроллере/DAO, в общем за пределами JSP. Средствами JDBC: создаем `Connection`, `создаем Statement`, `запускаем Statement`, забираем `ResultSet`.
2. Преобразуем данные в более/менее адекватное представление, например в список экземпляров класса, который эти данные оборачивает (т.н. Value Object, Data Transfer Object).
3. Передаем этот список в  JSP.
4. В JSP пробегаемся по списку и формируем табличку.

.

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="person" items="${people.people}">
  <tr>
    <td>${person.name}</td>
    <td>${person.age}</td>
    <td>${person.height}</td>
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблемка получить этот самый <code>"items"</code>

Comment: А в чем именно проблема?

Comment: получить доступ к таблице из jsp

Comment: Вы сами должны передать коллекцию из контроллера в JSP. Если вы вызываете JSP из простого сервлета forward-ом, то это будет выглядеть примерно так: `request.setAttribute("items", items);`. Ну и потом используете их в JSP.

Полистайте [Студенческий отдел кадров][1]

[1]:http://java-course.ru/students/students.php?name=part9

Comment: Спасибо, пригодилось!